# Australia Post shipping rate calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, e-commerce

Is anyone having any experience with any eCommerce application where you have calculated shipping rate on fly. I am in particular referring to Australia Post service.

Could you please guide me in right direction. I am thinking of using Provider pattern by which I can plugin any shipping provider according to user's profile.

Explanation as per Australia Post is what I am looking for but if anyone has got any suggestions using any other provider, I am fine.

FYI - I am referring to ASP.net, c# (.Net 4.0)
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Australia Post has a [Delivery Rate Calculator API](http://drc.edeliver.com.au/).

> The following instructions have been developed to enable you to access the functionality of the Post eDeliver Delivery Rate Calculator (DRC) directly from your merchant Website.  The DRC is available to merchants who would like to offer online estimation of delivery charges to their customers.

I haven't used it so can't tell you anymore about it.

Comment: I just tried this for kicks but it doesn't work - "charge=0 days=0 err_msg=Service is no longer available, please use other service type." - sorry, it IS working, just not for 'AIR' for some reason.

Comment: Like this: http://drc.edeliver.com.au/ratecalc.asp?Pickup_Postcode=4000&Destination_Postcode=2000&Country=AU&Weight=200&Service_Type=STANDARD&Length=100&Width=100&Height=100&Quantity=1

Comment: @Kirk - It also wouldn't let me send something from Bris to Melb by SEA ; ) Haha. http://drc.edeliver.com.au/ratecalc.asp?Pickup_Postcode=4000&Destination_Postcode=3000&Country=AU&Weight=300&Service_Type=SEA&Length=200&Width=200&Height=200&Quantity=1

Comment: Trick is that I used to work in Aust Post, and some items would go from Brisbane to Sydney via AIR and some would go by SURFACE.  Not sure what happens these days, though!

Comment: Guys, has anyone developed an app anytime for postage calculation using AusPost. If yes, could you please guide me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Step-1: create account and get Key

http://auspost.com.au/

Step2 : create function in your MyPage.aspx.cs page

```
protected string CalculateCharge(string lngth, string wdth, string hgth, string fpcode, string tpcode, string weght, string service_code)
        {
            string url = "https://auspost.com.au/api/postage/parcel/domestic/calculate.xml?";
            url = url + "length=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lngth) + "&width=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(wdth) + "&height=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(hgth) + "&from_postcode=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fpcode) + "&to_postcode=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tpcode) + "&option_code=&weight=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(weght) + "&service_code=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(service_code) + "&extra_cover=";
            Uri objURI = new Uri(url);
            HttpWebRequest objwebreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(objURI);
            objwebreq.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8;";
         
            objwebreq.Method = "Get";
            objwebreq.Timeout = 15000;
    
            objwebreq.Headers.Set("AUTH-KEY", "here enter your key");
          
            HttpWebResponse objWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objwebreq.GetResponse();
            Stream objStream = objWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
            return objStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
    
        }
```

Step-3: Pass Parameter in function
button click:

```
protected void btnShippingCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

            string xmlresult = CalculateCharge("10", "10", "10", "3216","3217" ,"5", "AUS_PARCEL_REGULAR");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlresult);
            ds.ReadXml(new System.IO.StringReader(doc.OuterXml));
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
         
        }
```

Note:

service_code:

AUS_PARCEL_REGULAR
AUS_PARCEL_EXPRESS
AUS_PARCEL_PLATINUM

Weight: in KG

That's It!!!